# OCAML: Parameter with multiple types

Tags: types, ocaml, reusability

Is it possible to have a parameter with multiple types in Ocaml?

I have defined two different types and both of those types have an address field:

```
type symbol =
  {
    address : string;
    name : string;
  }


type extern_symbol =
  {
    address : string;
    name : string;
    ...
  }
```

I also have a function which takes a *symbol list* as parameter and does checks with the *address* field. Now I'd like to reuse the code of the function for an *extern_symbol list*. The function would do exactly the same with the other list. Is there a way to get that done without having to write duplicate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly with record parameters, as all record types are distinct. There's no type for the notion of "any record with a field named `address` of type string". Hence you can't have a parameter of that type.

You could, of course, just pass the address to the function instead of the whole record if that's all you need.

Or you could pass a function that extracts the address:

```
let myfun address_of r =
    do_what_you_want (address_of r)

let internal_addr (r: symbol) = r.address
let external_addr (r: extern_symbol) = r.address

myfun internal_addr r1
myfun external_addr r2
```

So then `myfun` has a type like this:

```
(a -> string) -> a -> result
```

This generalizes to other operations that can be applied to both record types.

You can also use object types rather than records. There *is* a type for the notion of "any object with a method named `address` that returns a string":

```
< address : string; .. >
```

For example:

```
# let myfun2 ob = do_what_i_wanted ob#address;;
val myfun2 : < address : string; .. > -> string = <fun>
```

Finally, you could make the two types different variants of the same type:

```
type symbol =
   | Internal of { address: string; name: string }
   | External of { address: string; name: string; ... }
```

Then there would be no problem whatsoever handling them by the same function:

```
let myfun3 sym =
    let addr =
        match sym with
        | Internal x -> x.address
        | External x -> x.address
    in
    do_what_i_wanted addr
```

Comment: Minor note: `myfun3` could be written using pattern-matching: `let myfun3 (Internal {address; _} | External {address; _}) = do_what_i_wanted address`